# Retrieve path variable on Spring Boot WebFlux (functional approach)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

Let's say I have this router definition:

```
@Component
class PersonRouter(private val handler: PersonHandler) {
  @Bean
  fun router(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = router {
    ("/api/people" and accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).nest {
      GET("/{id}") { handler.findById(it) }
    }
  }
```

And then this handler:

```
@Component
@Transactional
class PersonHandler(private val repository: PersonRepository) {
  private companion object : KLogging()

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  fun findById(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    logger.info { "${req.method()} ${req.path()}" }
    val uuid = ? // req.pathContainer().elements().last().value()
    return ServerResponse.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(repository.findById(uuid)))
        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build())
  }
}
```

How do I access the identifier (what would be a `@PathVariable id: String` on a typical `@RestController`) from `ServerRequest` without doing black magic with regular expressions, string-heavy-lifting, and such things?

Comment: I don’t know what you’re trying to achieve but transactional annotations are not supported with WebFlux at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah! Found it!

It is by doing: `req.pathVariable("id")`

It was there all the time...in the official [Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-functions) (Web Reactive) documentation!

Comment: this option is not available when implementing a `ServerAuthenticationConverter` (for writing a security `WebFilter`) or any `WebFilter` for that matter...but this is an alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732355/how-to-get-path-variable-in-an-implementation-of-webfilter-serverwebexchange