# How to get path variable in an implementation of WebFilter? (ServerWebExchange)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive

Im working in a Spring Reactive application. I know how get a PathVariable in a interceptor with HttpServletRequest, some like that:

```
request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

But we had to make some changes and now we have a WebFilter implementation, so we don't use HttpServletRequest, instead we use ServerWebExchange

How can I get a Pathvariable from ServerWebExchange? Its possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no straightforward solution to that.

What you can do is the following :

`ServerWebExchange.getRequest()` will return `ServerHttpRequest` object, so you can extract `URI` from that object like this:

`URI uri = serverHttpRequest.getURI()`

Then,  using [UriTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html) you should be able to extract path variable values.

Here is example:

```
URI uri = new URI("abc.api.com/learn/sections/asdf-987/assignments/dsfwq98r7sdfg"); //suppose that your URI object is something like this
        String path = uri.getPath(); //get the path
        UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/learn/sections/{sectionId}/assignments/{assigmentId}"); //create template
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters = uriTemplate.match(path); //extract values form template
        System.out.println(parameters);
```

This will produce following output:

```
 {sectionId=asdf-987, assigmentId=dsfwq98r7sdfg}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was not the solution for my problem but maybe it could help someone else